# How long does it take to design a single wikihow illustration?

Tags: vector, illustration, sketching

On average, how long does it take to design a single wikihow illustration such as the one mentioned in the link below?

https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Scholarships

Comment: This is kind of impossible to answer definitively. What takes me 10 minutes may take someone else an hour, or vice versa. In addition, aptitude with a given software package may also play a role.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  There is no way to answer this question without guessing, and so I am voting to close this question because it is opinion based.

Comment: *Unfortunately*, this question is perilously close to being ***"how long is a piece of string?"*** as there are just *so many* factors involved which can impact the time required - as Scott and Lucian have said, an *awful lot* depends on the type of client, the tightness of their brief to the designer, how much to-and-fro interaction they require per design iteration, and how many iterations - and that's all independent of the skill of the designer, the depth of their familiarity with their tools, and whatever iterations might have been required for *technical* reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing between 2-3 up to 10-15-20 hours revisions included. Depends on skill level.

Comment: Then add 2 weeks for client notes `:)`

Comment: Yeah, and hopefully they're paying for it.